# Converting Ip Address to int (in_addr) for SWIG binding

Tags: sockets, python-2.7, swig

I have built a SWIF interface in python for some c ipset code (from DnsMasq)

It works with two big problems, the ip addresses are inserted into the IpSet backwards!
i.e. 127.0.0.1 becomes 1.0.0.127 and swig errors when i set the s_addr with converted ips around 192.x.x.x and higher...
I have played with endianess but when I do, or when i use high ip addresses i get

> in method 'in_addr_s_addr_set', argument 2 of type 'int'

This is my SWIG interface

```
    %module ipset
%{
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/utsname.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <linux/version.h>
#include <linux/netlink.h>   


extern void ipset_init(void);
int add_to_ipset(const char *setname, const struct in_addr *ipaddr, int flags, int remove);
 %}


struct in_addr {
            int s_addr;
};

extern void ipset_init(void);
int add_to_ipset(const char *setname, const struct in_addr *ipaddr, int flags, int remove);
```

This is my python

```
ina = ipset.in_addr()
aton = socket.inet_aton(ip)
sa = struct.unpack("!L",aton)[0]
ina.s_addr = sa
ipset.add_to_ipset("ipset-name", ina, socket.AF_INET, 0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the SWIG binding I needed an unsigned long

```
struct in_addr {
    unsigned long s_addr;
};
```

Still not sure why, but to fix the reversing i needed to unpack the integer as little endian.

```
sa = struct.unpack("<L",aton)[0]
```